# Fetch ordered records between specific ranks

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I ran a SQL query to order(sort) my records. Now how can I fetch not the top 1000 records by using limit but records between ranks of 500 to 800? I provide a specific range and get all records in that range of ranks?

Comment: Hint:  `OFFSET`.

Comment: Please define "rank". Exactly. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

If by "rank" you just mean row numbers, [`LIMIT` & `OFFSET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) will do:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY col OFFSET 499 LIMIT 301; -- "ranks of 500 to 800"
```

If you mean actual "rank" as implemented by the [window functions `rank()` or `dense_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) use the respective function in a subquery or CTE like demonstrated by @downernn.

Pesky side effect: `SELECT *` cannot be used to get all columns of the table. You get the additional column "rank" from the subquery unless you spell out the definitive list of desired columns.

Use the row type of the underlying table to work around this:

```
SELECT (sub.t).*   -- parentheses required!
FROM  (
   SELECT t, rank() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rnk  -- or dense_rank()?
   FROM   tbl t
   ) sub
ORDER  BY col1  -- repeart order (optional)
WHERE  rnk BETWEEN 500 AND 800;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the rank or row_number window function (do some research on their differences and choose the one that suits you) and an outer query to filter the rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT f1, f2, ..., RANK() OVER (ORDER BY fn, fm, ...) as r
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
)
WHERE r between 500 and 800
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`offset`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT).

```
-- Fetch rows 500 to 800 inclusive
select *
from generate_series(1, 1000)
order by 1
limit 301
offset 499
```

`offset` is the number of rows to skip, to start at row 500 you skip the first 499 rows. `limit` is 301 because there's 301 rows between 500 and 800 inclusive. Use 300 if you want 500 to 800 exclusive.